# Cannot edit question closed as off-topic (company-specific)?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, editing, deleted-questions

My question at https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/168304/uncomfortable-with-dress-code-not-in-a-customer-facing-position was closed as off-topic:

> Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department. Questions that address only a specific company or position are of limited use to future visitors. Questions seeking legal advice should be directed to legal professionals. For more information, click here.

The question isn't specific to my company's policy but rather "*how to approach a supervisor at a new job about the issue of dress code*" in general. There is a similar question [What is Generally Meant by "No Tennis Shoes" in a Dress Code](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/162595/what-is-generally-meant-by-no-tennis-shoes-in-a-dress-code) that asks about an ambiguous policy, whereas the objective goal of my question is to ask how to approach my supervisor about an unambiguous policy. I think neither of the questions are necessarily company-specific.

In the comments I see that Joe Strazzere provided advice that is a perfectly valid answer to anyone in my situation, regardless of company.

I just tried to edit the question to word it in a more general way for it to be on-topic but the error message "This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed" appeared. There is an "Edit question" button on the Closed banner so I would have thought that the community could reopen the question if it was edited to better fit the guidelines.

I see questions being closed and reopened here and elsewhere on Stack Exchange so I am wondering why this question was deleted before there was even a chance to improve it?

Comment: Posted an answer for your consideration. If what you want is to submit the post to be considered for reopening by the community, you should post a Meta Post here with the [meta-tag:reopen-request] tag and asking why you think it's on topic.

Comment: @DarkCygnus Thank you. I still think that the wording of the question can be improved to focus on the *how* instead of a yes/no answer to be more on-topic, though I already got an "answer" to it from Joe's comment so I will proceed based on that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I see questions being closed and reopened here and elsewhere on Stack Exchange so I am wondering why this question was deleted before there was even a chance to improve it?

Checking the activity log on the post I see the following:

- Posted 18h ago
- Several comments seeking for clarification asked after that
- Post Closed 10h ago (that is, after 8 hours of asking for clarification and no feedback received from your part)
- Post Deleted 6h ago (that is 12h after you posted it and gave no feedback on it nor attempted to edit).

This tells us that **there actually was time and chances for the question to be improved**, as several comments were posted between the time of creation of the post and it's eventual deletion 6h ago. **It simply happened that you were engaged on the post and, naturally, eventually got closed/deleted**.

**This site is a bit more active than other SE sites**, probably because the users/questions posted ratio. In other words, questions posted on TWP promptly get feedback and clarification and also are closed/deleted more swiftly than other sites (for example SO... in SO it may be days before you get your first comment asking for clarification).

Furthermore, I see that the question you linked to that is similar captures very well your situation and the course of action to take (that is, ask your boss/HR). I feel that the top answer on the question you linked (https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/162606/73791) fits well to your scenario. Given these facts, I am reluctant to reopen the post, as the one you liked seems to be a valid dupe candidate.

---

**tl;dr:** Your post received feedback and chances to improve, but you weren't engaged and eventually got closed (for lack of clarification and improvements I guess) and finally deleted... Try to be more engaged in the future here on TWP as users on this site are more active and posts get feedback way faster than other Stacks.

Finally, the questions you ask seem to be not quite good ("do I ask...?" is a choice yes/no question, which is off-topic, as it is also "should I wait...?"). Then, the question you linked ([What is Generally Meant by "No Tennis Shoes" in a Dress Code](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/162595/what-is-generally-meant-by-no-tennis-shoes-in-a-dress-code)), seems to be a similar case to yours, and the advice there given can be extrapolated to your case (which the answer would be *yes, ask your boss about the dress code, yes do it now*)

Comment: Uh... We don't usually delete questions here in 12 hours, I don't think this is good advice.  I assume it got deleted for cause by Neo because it got flagged by users including myself.

Comment: @mxyzplk you misunderstood. I never said we delete in average in 12h... sometimes posts go wayy faster, sometimes they take longer. What I said is that (1) OP wasn't engaged in the whole process until the post got closed, and even then deleted and (2) that this site post interaction is faster than other sites like SO where feedback takes days to come. OP didn't ask "why was this deleted.period.", OP asked "why was this deleted without a chance to improve", so the key aspect is "without chance to improve", which is what I covered in the answer...

Comment: There is no expectation that people jump on their posts to improve them within 12 hours.  I am pro deleting this question but this seems very misleading to me.

Comment: @mxyzplk IIRC there was some guidance somewhere asking posters not to "shoot and run"... to remain engaged at least in the first moments after they post their Q (don't have the time to search for the link now, but it makes sense as it would avoid good posts being closed by hasty users that won't wait for OP to come back)... and even if there was not expectation for users to be engaged, in practice it is expected, to be able to correct details and enhance, and get better help... anyways, I wouldn't feed the troll any more ;) I gave my two cents on the engagement part. The closing was obvious.

Comment: @mxyzplk I see that questions have been closed in the past for duplicates/off-topic but a closed question can still be improved with the Edit feature. Why do you think that this question should be deleted rather than closed?

Comment: Because it is obvious trolling and doesn’t belong on the site.  There is no real answer (how do you ask?  You open your mouth and ask) and it’s clearly just a goof for whatever reason, and therefore not welcome on this site.  In that spirit I won’t respond further to this, but I felt it was important to make the point that legit questions aren’t required to engage or be deleted in half a day.

Comment: @mxyzplk yup you are correct, nobody is **required** to engage nor to delete in half a day, and nowhere in my post I mentioned that those things are **required**... in practice it's quite different though, and that's what I pointed out with my two cents of advice so OP and everyone can **consider** for when they post (again, not requiring, which is your confusion, and still I am quite sure that the engaged part is mentioned somewhere, will search for it when I get some time).

Comment: @mxyzplk A search for "how to ask" on this site come up with many questions about various topics usually with answers containing example conversations which is what I was looking for. My question was closed for being "company-specific" and I feel that it can be worded better to emphasize the goal (as described in this meta question) without it being company-specific. Why are you attacking it as "obvious trolling"?

Comment: @CoryCarter if you have a better phrasing, more clear, with a goal we can help, is not a choice question (see [help/dont-ask]) then perhaps try posting it with the improved phrasing and content, consider being engaged to feedback and clarification, and let's see how it goes from there (what mxyzplk was saying that the question was quite unbelievable, and seemed like potential trollish in nature... perhaps if you clarified it wouldn't have appeared that way).

Comment: @mxyzplk you would be correct.

Comment: In reading the deleted question, I can only imagine the shock and horror of anyone seeing me in the required dress code